# Allure @Issues Annotation causes Unexpected token Exception in groovy/geb

Tags: groovy, geb, allure

We use Geb/Spock framework for executing automated tests and Allure for test reporting.

I have problem when I want to use the annotation @Issues:

```
import spock.lang.PendingFeature
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations.Issue 
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations.Issues 

@Issues({  
      @Issue("JEE-3559"), 
      @Issue("JEE-3560") 
})
@PendingFeature
def '24ChildFields' () {
     when:
     boolean successful = performChildFields ()
     then:
     successful == true
}
```

The compiler reported an

> unexpected token: @

after first issue. Do I have to declare this in a different way or why it doesn't work like the other annotations?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am using allure 1.5.4. version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed a [closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) to `@Issues()` annotation instead of an array. Following code will work in Java:

```
@Issues({  
      @Issue("JEE-3559"), 
      @Issue("JEE-3560") 
})
```

In Groovy you declare an array using `[]`, so in your case it should be:

```
@Issues([  
      @Issue("JEE-3559"), 
      @Issue("JEE-3560") 
])
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution

Comment: @Pia I'm glad I could help you :)